# Automatic pull to refresh in Android on activity start

Tags: android, android-view, pull-to-refresh

I am using this library Android-PullToRefresh:
https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh

It works nice, but I need to implement automatic 'pull to refresh' on activity start, that is having the same visual and functional effect as pulling down the list just triggered automatically instead of user pull gestures. Do you know if I can do this ?
Thank you

Comment: I suppose you're invoking some method which does some network activity and refreshes the list if pulled. What's the problem with calling that logic in an `AsyncTask` when your activity is created?

Comment: But I need the visual effect of the list being pulled, that listview loading header being shown and after operation is done it should slide up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just call

```
mPullToRefreshList.setRefreshing();
```